# How can we dynamically change a few dropdown lists using a database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu

Trying to dynamically change dropdown list values from mysql database. Script seems like workin but I'm not sure. The database columns are  id, columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD

On second dropdown-list selection, it gives the alert 'hi again'.

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$(".columnA").change(
function() {
    var dataA=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'columnA='+ dataA;
    $.ajax (    {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_try.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $(".columnB").html(html);
                    }    
                }               
            );

            }
    );

$(".columnB").change(
function() {
    var dataB=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'columnB='+ dataB;
    $.ajax (    {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_try.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        alert("hi.. again");
                        $(".columnC").html(html);
                    }    
                }               
            );

            }
    );
```

});

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['columnA'])
{
$columnA = $_POST['columnA'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, columnB FROM try WHERE columnA = '$columnA' GROUP BY columnB");

//$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, columnB FROM try columnB WHERE columnA = '$columnA'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$columnB = $row['columnB'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnB.'</option>';

}
}


if($_POST['columnB'])
{
$columnB = $_POST['columnB'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, columnC FROM try WHERE columnB = '$columnB' GROUP BY columnC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$columnC = $row['columnC'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnC.'</option>';

}
}

?>
```

Ok I think html code make it easier to understand the problem..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
.....
here is the script
...
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="15%"><span style="font-size:20px;">columnA</span></td>
    <td><span >
        <select size="1" id="columnA" title="" name="columnA" class="columnA"  style="width:250px; height:40px; font-size:20px; padding: 5px;">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
        <?php
            include('db.php');
            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT columnA FROM try GROUP BY columnA");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {
            //$id = $row['id'];
            $dataA = $row['columnA'];
            echo '<option value="'.$dataA.'">'.$dataA.'</option>';
            } 
        ?>
        </select>
        </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="15%"><span style="font-size:20px;">columnB</span></td>
    <td>
        <select size="1" id="columnB"  title="" name="columnB" class="columnB" style="width:250px; height:40px; font-size:20px; padding: 5px;">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="15%"><span style="font-size:20px;">columnC</span></td>
    <td>
        <select size="1" id="columnC"  title="" name="columnC" class="columnC" style="width:250px; height:40px; font-size:20px; padding: 5px;">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose..</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what problem you're having?

Comment: Make a reduced test case http://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/ That's the easiest way to solve it on your own.

Comment: @MartinBean When I select first value from dropdownlist1(ddl1) its ok, displaying the values at ddl2 but when I select a value from ddl2, ddl3 shows nothing.

Comment: @pikk why you are trying to print $row['columnB'] when you are going for columnC.A better is just use firebug and see what's going on inside console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be tempted to just select all the rows from your table in one query, and then use JavaScript (or jQuery) to change the select list options. This saves HTTP requests, as for each change your firing an AJAX event, and if the user changes the option 100 times, that's 100 requests just for aesthetic reasons.

Another benefit is, if the user for some reason doesn't have JavaScript or is on a slow connection, then the select lists are still usable, as otherwise they'll be blank because they haven't been loaded by your AJAX call.

Comment: Hmm, I think my table has about 1000-2000 records, is it still a useful option for me?

Comment: I don't see why the numbers would effect it. One database query and one HTTP request is more preferable that multiple database calls and numerous HTTP requests. Plus, you can always cache your database query for future requests.

Comment: Ok. I'll reorganize my codes in accordance with your suggestion. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $columnC = $row['columnC'];
   echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnC.'</option>';
}
```

You're printing columnB, while you should print columnC

Comment: Show me the output of the ajax request after changing column B, and remove `echo "deneme..";` because I think your browser now breaks the html.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I changed the line `echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$columnC.'</option>';`  with this one **echo '<option value="'.$columnC.'">'.$columnC.'</option>';**